# What should I do to read strings in c?

Tags: c, string

```
int main(){
    char s[]="hi ";    
    char t[55];
    fgets(t,55,stdin); 
    strcat(s,t);
    puts(s);
}
```

I want to concatenate the strings `s` and the entered string `t`, but I'm not getting any output. I have tried using `gets` to read the `string` but the compiler says "use of gets can be dangerous". What should I do?

Comment: You should start reading a good C book...

Comment: BTW: forget `gets`, use `fgets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strcat(s,t);` is overrunning the destination memory buffer `s`, as it is only large enough for 4 characters (and one of those is occupied by the NUL-terminator).

The behaviour of your program is therefore *undefined*.

Make the size of `s` large enough to accommodate its initial contents *plus* the largest string possible in `t`.

Comment: But even if i try printf(" %s%s ",s,t); instead of concating . the output will print only s part i.e. hi

Comment: But even if i use 'printf("%s %s",s,t);' instead of concating. Program gives output of s alone .

Comment: @bhartendupandya can't reproduce, here it works fine. Maybe you should post another question for this issue.`int main() {
  char s[] = "hi ";
  char t[55];
  fgets(t, 55, stdin);
  printf(" %s%s ", s, t);
}` works fine here.

Answer (score 3):

The array `s` doesn't have enough space to append `t` to it. You need to increase its size sufficiently.

```
char s[]="hi ";
```

is an array of 4 characters. It can't hold more any more bytes that you'd want to append. Thus the your code has [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you increase the array size, for example, to 100:

```
char s[100]="hi ";
```

Now, you'd be able to append further 96 bytes to it.

In cases in C, you always have to think of overrunning buffers.

NB: You should also check if `fgets()` succeeded before attempting to append `t`. In case, `fgets()` failed, the contents of `t` is *indeterminate*.

Answer (score 3):

The character array `s` should have enough memory to accommodate the string read in the array `t`. Thus it should be declared at least like

```
char t[55];
char s[sizeof( t ) + 3] = "hi ";
```

Also the function `fgets` can append the string by the new line character. In general you should remove it. This can be done the following way

```
t[strcspn( t, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

Take into account that according to the C standard function main without parameters should be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The program must contain headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

here was the same question asked

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

use fgets instead